# How can I extract the required data from these three tables using mysql?

Tags: mysql

Sorry but I'm struggling to work out the correct SQL to extract the required data from these three tables...

```
users:- id, firstname, lastname, email, live
contracts:- id, userid, contractid
userstage:- id, userid, stageid, statusid
```

I need firstname, lastname, email, live, from users
and contractid from contracts,
and statusid from userstage

```
WHERE users.live =1 AND contracts.contractid = 1 AND userstage.statusid <>4 (not equal to 4)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty basic SQL. Don't really see what your problem is. You might want to change to OUTER JOIN (left or right) depending on what you need.

```
SELECT u.firstname, u.lastname, u.email, u.live, c.contractid, us.statusid
FROM users AS u
INNER JOIN contracts AS c ON u.id = c.userid
INNER JOIN userstage AS us ON u.id = us.userid
WHERE u.live = 1 AND c.contractid = 1 AND us.statusid <> 4
```

Comment: Ok, this is what I was trying, but the results are not adding up. If i leave out the statusid i get 900 results which is roughly twice the number of users in the users table.

Comment: The contracts and userstage tables both have multiple entries per userid. Does this help to get the right join? If I change to OUTER JOIN i just get mysql errors

Comment: Ok sorry, these work fine. It's just that i've got multiple lines per user id, which is to be expected, and i didn't realise. Thank you both.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to do when some of the users have no contracts etc, you can start with:

```
SELECT  firstname, lastname, email, live, contractid, statusid 
FROM users
JOIN contracts ON contracts.userid = users.id
JOIN userstage ON userstage.userid = users.id
WHERE users.live =1 AND contracts.contractid = 1 AND userstage.statusid <>4 (not equal to 4)
```